# How to easily create dissimilarity matrix from vector of differences?

Tags: r

In my research each subject was given n*(n-1)/2 questions about his subjective opinion about dissimilarity between n=5 objects (for later use with 3-way multidimensional scaling).

I want to create a dissimilarity matrix from the 10-item vector v, arranged e.g. in the following fashion (for n=5):

```
  1
  2 5
  3 6 8
  4 7 9 10
```

This is a code sample code for achieving it for this particular n:

```
dissim<-rep(0,n*n)
dim(dissim)<-c(5,5)
dissim[2,1]<-v[1]
dissim[3,1]<-v[2]
dissim[4,1]<-v[3]
dissim[5,1]<-v[4]
dissim[3,2]<-v[5]
dissim[4,2]<-v[6]
dissim[5,2]<-v[7]
dissim[4,3]<-v[8]
dissim[5,3]<-v[9]
dissim[5,4]<-v[10]
```

Is there any utility function which helps doing it for any n? I know I can use two nested loops to do it, but the code would be more clear if I used a dedicated function.

And maybe I would learn about the existence of another useful library in the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n <- 5
mat <- matrix(0, ncol = n, nrow = n)
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- 1:10
mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    2    5    0    0    0
[4,]    3    6    8    0    0
[5,]    4    7    9   10    0
```

Comment: This is better to my own solution as it doesn't rely on internal structure of objects. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Er... By chance I found the solution myself. It so happens, that the internal structure of the dist object is *just the vector v*. So what works is this:

```
dissim<-v
class(dissim)='dist'
attr(dissim,"Size")<-5
dissim<-as.dist(dissim)
```

It works now, but I am not sure if this is a documented way and will always be valid.

Comment: It depends on how are you going to use it, because `as.matrix(dissim)` shows full matrix, which is not the one that you need, i.e. distance matrix is symmetric and it is enough to print only lower triangle.